getComputedStyle/getPropertyValue returns wrong results in extension
I’m building a Safari extension. I’m dealing with a DOM element whose -webkit-user-select style property is set to 'none'. I can see that in the browser developer tools.
However, when I programmatically access the same element from within the context of my extension, the same property evaluates to an empty string, as if it weren’t set. This happens even after I check the value manually in the developer tools.
window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('-webkit-user-select');
// => ''

For context, I’m iterating over a bunch of elements in the user’s selection to decide how to process them. Maybe that has something to do with it but I don’t know.
function anyIllegalElements(selection) {
  return !!selectedElements(selection).filter(el => {
    return window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('-webkit-user-select') === 'none' ||
      window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('user-select') === 'none' ||
      el.tagName === 'IFRAME';
  }).length;
}

What’s going on here? I know that this behavior would be expected if I tried accessing the properties directly, but I’m using getPropertyValue as advised.

Side note: you'd better use .some instead of .filter

Seems like if browser supports non-prefixed property it drops the prefix in the computed style.

If you’re suggesting that window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('user-select') should hold the correct value: it doesn’t. It’s an empty string, too.

Is there any difference, if you don't test this from within the extension context, but via the browser console? (Maybe with less complicated code that doesn't iterate over a user selection, but rather by accessing the element you know has this styling applied, directly.)

Yes, difference. window.getComputedStyle($0).getPropertyValue('-webkit-user-select'); => 'none'

C3roe’s comment helped me get there.
The way I got those elements before iterating over them is through cloneContents(). I learned the hard way that cloned elements apparently do not retain their original styles.
